# How to get rid of duplicated pairs of id's from two column query result

Tags: sql, sqlite, duplicates, inner-join, self-join

I got file information in one table and file_id and checksums stored in other one. Now i want to search for duplicate files in table with checksums

```
SELECT A.file_id pid, B.file_id sid
FROM checksums A INNER JOIN checksums B ON A.checksum = B.checksum
WHERE A.file_id <> B.file_id
ORDER BY pid
```

Result I got is fairly good and can be used after further processing. What I'm wondering about is  if and how I could get right result straight from query. I mean here to get rid of "cross duplicates" in these two columns. for example if **File** with **id 1** got duplicates with **Files** that got **id 43,77,14** and **id 2** with duplicate in file with **id 74** then i get following result

```
| pid | sid |
=============
|  1  |  43 |
|  1  |  77 |
|  1  |  14 |
|  2  |  74 |
...
|  14 |   1 |
...
|  43 |   1 |
...
|  74 |   2 |
...
|  77 |   1 |
...
```

And what I want to achieve to get rid of one of these opposite pairs to avoid duplicate results, is there way in SQL to do it?

Comment: Are all rows duplicated?

Comment: In my current query result all rows have "opposite pair"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an inequality condition should be sufficient:

```
SELECT a.file_id pid, b.file_id sid
FROM checksums a 
INNER JOIN checksums b ON b.checksum = a.checksum
WHERE A.file_id < B.file_id
ORDER BY pid
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to work as I originally intended, but still i got impression that your solution is too simple to be good or i have not enough brains to wrap my mind around it.

Comment: @MoreThanChaos: this answers the question that you asked. You wanted to get rid of "mirror" records: using `<` (or, similarly, `>`) instead of `<>` does just that, and nothing else.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not sufficient and my worries came true, tests did revealed that it only works in case of particular data set, when data are "fresh" and table was not used, all was fine. When some entries got deleted and some new was added there are cases when, for example there should be one row result but it doesnt work because A A.file_id > B.file_id